# Disable Company Approval Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento-cloud

In my project whenever any user visits the front-end & creates an account. Company form is displayed. After entering all valid information, an email is sent to the user to set a password. After this, the admin approves the account from the backend.

I want to modify this requirement i.e. I want to add new fields password/confirm password over the same form & want to set auto-approval of all the accounts i.e. I want all accounts to set password on the form. No email to set password & no approval will be required from admin. I want this as default magento flow work. Is this possible? Please confirm

Rashi

Comment: By default, Magento 2 already shows password and confirm password fields on the User registeration page and there is no approval requirement on default Magento 2. Are you using any type of modification if so please mention theme or related extensions you're using.

Comment: @NathaOdedara It's Magento B2B i.e. company form where no password fields are on the form. On account creation email is sent to the customer for password & further admin approval is required for account. FYI, follow this URL https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-company-create.html for knowledge. Please share your knowledge if my point is clear to you. Do I need to create custom module for this

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you're talking about customer registration. I just checked and you're correct, In B2B, in order to achieve what you want in Company Registration, you need to create an extension with few modifications.

Comment: any guide for the same?

Comment: Would love to help you out, but the modifications will need a lot of explanation. Please click on link to talk our chat and not spam in comment section. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131523/company-registration-in-magento2

Comment: Due to less reputation I am not able to start. Any other way-out please?

Comment: I have dropped a message in the chatroom, I hope you can read message there. If not please let me know here.

Comment: Thanks. Let's connect over there

Comment: Thanks @NathaOdedara yyou solution worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

I followed steps-

1. Override Create.phtml file for 2 custom fields
2. Override module-company Controller file i.e. CreatePost.php for setting
   password value
3. Changed the db_schema.xml file to set the default
   value of the status column as active

My module is perfectly working fine after submit.

Thanks for the help @Natha.

Answer (score 0):

Please Disable from here

> Stores > Settings > Configuration -> B2B Features

Comment: where in the B2B Features. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: There's no such option under B2B Features section to achieve what the op wants.

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/b2b-features.html

Comment: may above link help you

Comment: Thanks Gohil but the customization I want are not managed from backend